# python for loop in column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just want to make a dictionary with the value of cate4 column in dataframe
but seems all value in the dictionary are same

the cate_content table is like below

| cate4 | content |
| --- | --- |
| A | sentence1 |
| B | sentence2 |

```
cate_dict = {}
noun_lists = []
for cate in cate_list:
  for content in cate_content[cate_content['cate4']==cate].content:
    noun_list = nlpy.nouns(content)
    for noun in noun_list:
      noun_lists.append(noun)
  cate_dict[cate] = noun_lists
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: what is nlpy here? what is cate_content here?

Comment: {'A':[noun1, noun2, noun3 ... ] , 'B' :[nounA, nounB, nounC ...] }

Comment: nlpy is the language tokenizing package

Answer (score 0):

Use to_dict(). Just make sure you tokenize the whole column before and that's it (or tokenize later, but in any case, that's not the problem proposed here).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[2,3,4,5,6]})
records = df.to_dict(orient='records')
[{i["a"]: i["b"]} for i in records]
>> [{1: 2}, {2: 3}, {3: 4}, {4: 5}, {5: 6}]
```

Comment: This is definitely not what OP wants.

Comment: Correct, I edited. Now it does.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, try this:

```
{row.cate4: nlpy.nouns(row.content) for _, row in cate_content.iterrows()}
```

Comment: seems it doesn't work for my case. it contains only the last row :(

Answer (score 0):

Actaully just to make sure,
I want to table to dict like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vn1A.png)

{'A': ['I', 'ate','banana','I','drank','water'…... ]} , 'B' : ['I', 'love','you','I',hate','you','I' …..]}

Comment: You should not use an answer to add details to the question. Please edit your question.